# how to update an email with unique role in Form Request Validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I need to update an email with a unique role in the Form Request Validation. I have no problem with creating the user, but the problem is when I try to update the email, it shows that the email is already taken. how can I do something like if the email that is in the input value is owned by the user it can be skipped by the unique role.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => ['sometimes', 'required','email:rfc,dns', 'unique:users,email', 'max:255'],
```

in controller

```
public function update(UsersRequest $request, $id)
{
    
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->save();}
```

blade code

```
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $user->email }}" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the update method. so obviously you have a user id that is going to be updated so just fetch the user first,

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
```

Now the validation will be,

```
'email' => ['sometimes', 'required','email:rfc,dns', ($this->email === $this->user->email) ? '' : 'unique:users,email', 'max:255'],
```

Let me know its solves your issue or not.

Comment: I am working with Form Request Validation (App\Http\Requests) how can I fetch ($id) and ($request). i am sorry but I am new to Laravel

Comment: @ShadyHesham can you please share your update method signature?

Comment: `$id` is the user id that you have to update and `$request` is an object of `\Illuminate\Http\Request`. In the request object, you get the `POST` data.

Comment: you can see it now, I have already edited it.

Comment: Try this validation `'email' => ['sometimes', 'required','email:rfc,dns', ($this->request->email === $this->user->email) ? '' : 'unique:users,email', 'max:255'],` @ShadyHesham let me know the results.

Comment: unfortunately i've got this error Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::$email

Comment: @ShadyHesham Try this `'email' => ['sometimes', 'required','email:rfc,dns', ($this->email === $this->user->email) ? '' : 'unique:users,email', 'max:255']`.

Comment: thank you, it works well perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @ShadyHesham, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
               'email' => 'required|email|max:199|unique:users,email',
               
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
               'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $this->user->id, 
            
            ];
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but your code does not work :(

Comment: public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $request->validate([
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
  ]);
}

Comment: i am working with Form Request Validation (\Illuminate\Http\Request). can you see my code again, I updated the code

Comment: You can show me

Comment: you can see the original post

Answer (score 0):

This is what i prefer
First, your update route must have a `{user}` as parameter
`Route::put('/users/{user}', ...);`

You can also use in your request file

```
$unique_email = 'unique:users,email';
if ($user = $this->route('user')) {
    $unique_email .= ',' . $user->id;
}

// And then add it to rule

return [
    'email' => ['sometimes', 'required', $unique_email],
];
```